# Assigning i18n to default parameter - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization

```
const AlertDialog = ({ title = "Alert", ...props }) => {
  return (
   <div>{title}</div>
  );
};
```

I want to assign an i18n translation to the default value here, in this case "title", but I can only initialize the "t" after the param. Is there anyway I can translate the default value without having to use useEffect?

What I wanted/imagined it to do, parent will pass a translated string down to child here, and if no value is passed, it should use the default translation

For example:

> <AlertDialog title={t(pathToJson,"Something Else")}/>

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const AlertDialog = ({ title = t(pathToJson,"Alert"), ...props }) => {
  return (
   <div>{title}</div>
  );
};
```

Alternative I can think of but not what I want

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const AlertDialog = ({ title, ...props }) => {

const [translation, setTranslation] = useState('Alert')

useEffect(() => 
{
 if(title === undefined){
    setTranslation('Alert');
 }else{
    setTranslation(t(pathToJson, 'Alert'))
 }
},[])


return (
   <div>{translation}</div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure who have solved this issue by now, but I am going to write my suggestion anyways. My suggestion is to handle everything outside of AlertDialog component. like this:

```
<AlertDialog title={pathToJson ? t(pathToJson)} : t("Alert")} />
```